# Shorthand for \leftarrow?

Tags: symbols

Just out of curiosity: As the command `\rightarrow` has the shorthand `\to`, is there a corresponding shorthand for `\leftarrow`?

Comment: Yes, it's `\gets`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The command `\to` is not documented in the LaTeX manual; it is in LaTeX just because it is in Plain TeX and, in the olden times, it was frequent that people transferred code from Plain TeX to LaTeX.

So in the LaTeX kernel we find

```
350 \DeclareMathSymbol{\leftarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"20}
351    \let\gets=\leftarrow
352 \DeclareMathSymbol{\rightarrow}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"21}
353    \let\to=\rightarrow
```

(the file is `fontmath.ltx`). The abbreviation you're looking for is `\gets`, which isn't documented in the manual, either.

Both commands should be mentioned, of course.

Comment: @Chou Not a trouble at all: as I said, those commands *should* be documented.